# Python how to map categorical values into new numeric values without getting the indices must be integer error?

Tags: python

I need to map some categorical values to integers. I tried the solution from [this link](https://github.com/minsuk-heo/kaggle-titanic/blob/master/titanic-solution.ipynb) at `In[24]`:

```
title_mapping = {"Mr": 0, "Miss": 1, "Mrs": 2, 
                 "Master": 3, "Dr": 3, "Rev": 3, "Col": 3, "Major": 3, "Mlle": 3,"Countess": 3,
                 "Ms": 3, "Lady": 3, "Jonkheer": 3, "Don": 3, "Dona" : 3, "Mme": 3,"Capt": 3,"Sir": 3 }
for dataset in train_test_data:
    dataset['Title'] = dataset['Title'].map(title_mapping)
```

From my script:

```
for dataset in train:
    dataset['Title'] = dataset['Title'].map(title_mapping)
```

And here is the dataframe with the Title field:

[image]

I am keep getting the following error:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with the full error message

Comment: It's ```pandas``` you are talking about, right? You're also missing dot at the end of each title, your dataframe seems to have dots.

Comment: what is `type` of train?

Comment: @Akhilesh dataframe

Comment: in your provided link it is a `list`. so you need not to iterate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is probably because you are trying to iterate from your `train` DataFrame instead of the list of DataFrames `train_test_data`.

Try simply doing:

```
train['Title'] = train['Title'].map(title_mapping)
```

The notebook you are basing on first creates a list of dataframes at [21]:

```
train_test_data = [train, test]
```

So when it is iterating at [24] it first goes thru `train` and then `test` fully, which it's whats needed when mapping a column.

By the way, if you ever want to iterate row by row from a DataFrame, do like this:

```
for index_value, row in df.iterrows():
    print(index_value)
    # you can work for each column from that row:
    print(row['column_name'])

>>> 0
>>> I'm a column value
```